# matching string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Alright, so i need to be able to match strings in ways that give me more flexibility.
so, here is an example. for instance, if i had the string "This is my random string", i would want some way to make

```
" *random str* ",
" *is __ ran* ", 
" *is* ", 
" *this is * string ",
```

all match up with it, i think at this point a simple true or false would be okay to weather it match's or not, but id like basically * to be any length of any characters, also that _ would match any one character. i can't think of a way, although im sure there is, so if possible, could answers please contain code examples, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused that since the question is tagged with regex (it doesn't look to be a subsequent edit), what you're looking for that's different from regexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do, but in response to:

> but id like basically * to be any length of any characters, also that _ would match any one character

In regex, you can use `.` to match any single character and `.+` to match any number of characters (at least one), or `.*` to match any number of characters (or none if necessary).

So your `*is __ ran*` example might turn into the regex `.+is .. ran.+`, whilst `this is * string` could be `this is .+ string`.

If this doesn't answer your question then you might want to try re-wording it to make it clearer.

For learning more regex syntax, a popular site is [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info/), which provides pretty much everything you need to get started.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex).

In C#, you would use the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class.

For example:

```
var str = "This is my random string";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str, ".*is .. ran.*"));    //Prints "True"
```

Comment: Pre-emptive snarky comment: Now you'll have two problems!

Comment: Given that the OP has tagged his question with `regex`, I think he's looking for something a bit more specific. :)